# How to change the behavior of double click on table in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench, double clicking on a table object pastes the table name into the query file currently in focus.

Can it be changed? I would like to see table contents when double clicking on it. 
Or at least, disable the current behavior.
Is that possible? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, but do consider submitting a feature request.

For now, hover your cursor to the right of the table name and click the desired icon... in this case, click the one that shows the table contents (as it executes "SELECT * FROM tablename").

Comment: Thanks, I know about this option, but I keep forgetting and double clicking instead, which adds the table name to the query where the cursor is standing at the moment and upsets me every time :)